# Dropzone not saving images in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, dropzone.js, laravel-6

I've implemented Dropzone into my form and Now I want to save all the images in my "Uploads" directory.
The issue is that on Submit Form, images are not saving into directory. There is neither error on console under Network Tab nor on webpage.
Also, Mu upload directory is empty.

I need suggestions.

Blade

```
    <form method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="msform" action="/reports">
      @csrf
       <div name="gallery"  id="dropzoneForm" class="dropzone">
         <div class="fallback">
           <input id="files" multiple="true" name="file" type="file">
         </div>
       </div>
   <input type="submit" id="submit_multiple_form" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

Javascript

```
 <script>
      Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
      url: "/reports",
      autoProcessQueue : false,
      acceptedFiles : ".png,.jpg,.gif,.bmp,.jpeg",
      uploadMultiple: true,
      parallelUploads: 5,
      maxFiles: 15,
      maxFilesize: 1,
      acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
      addRemoveLinks: true,
      dictDefaultMessage: "Click here to browse or Drag & Drop your files",

       init:function(){
         var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit_multiple_form");
         myDropzone = this;

         submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
           myDropzone.processQueue();
         });

         this.on("complete", function(){
           if(this.getQueuedFiles().length == 0 && this.getUploadingFiles().length == 0)
           {
             var _this = this;
             _this.removeAllFiles();
           }
         });
       }
};
</script>
```

Controller

```
public function multiStepStore(Request $request)
{
  if($request->hasFile('file'))
  {
  $file = $request->file;
  $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $imageName = time() . '.' . $extension;
  $file->move(public_path('src/uploads'), $imageName);

  return response()->json(['success' => $imageName]);

  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your PHP code? Does an image reach PHP?

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov Do you have any Idea ?

Comment: Would you please dd the request and paste the output here `dd($request->all());`

Comment: @STA 
dd($request->all());  returns empty array, don't know why.

Comment: @Shaan,  the problem is on your js. Check the console and find the error

Comment: @STA
I already mentioned that there is no any error on console. 
That's a confusing situation :(

Comment: @Shaan bro check the email :)

Comment: @KhalidKhan I just text you. 
Thanks

Comment: @Shaan check again bro :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that we need to add **token into Dropzone Options**.
Here is my resolved code according to question.

Blade

```
    <form method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="msform" action="/reports">
      @csrf
       <div id="dropzoneForm" class="dropzone"></div>
   <input type="submit" id="submit_multiple_form" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
      Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
      url: "/reports",
      autoProcessQueue : false,
      dictDefaultMessage: "Click here to browse or Drag & Drop your files",
      sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {
          formData.append("_token", "{{ csrf_token() }}");
      },

       .................................
</script>
```

Controller

```
public function multiStepStore(Request $request)
{
  if ($request->file('file')!=null)
  {
  $file = $request->file;
  $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $imageName = time() . '.' . $extension;
  $file->move(public_path('src/uploads'), $imageName);

  return response()->json(['success' => $imageName]);

  }
}
```

Now My Dropzone is working in normal form. Yeah !!!!!!!!